# Laravel Vite Can't Use JS Functions Globally

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite

I'm using Laravel with Vite. But I'm having a trouble. I have multiple JS files and including them whenever I want to use. But I cannot use the function I created in one file in another file.

I have an **app.js** file looks like this:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = jQuery;

import './bootstrap';
import './main.js';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();
```

And I have a function like this in **main.js**:

```
function testFunction() {
    alert('test');
}
```

I put Vite definitions to my layout blade like this:

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

I have another page contains another JS file like this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')


@endsection

@section('scripts')
    @vite(['resources/js/edit-note-page.js'])
@endsection
```

And in that JS file I want to use the function that I mentioned in the beginning like this:

```
testFunction();
```

But I'm getting an **Uncaught ReferenceError: testFunction is not defined** error in console. I couldn't figure it out. What is the correct way to do it?

I'm using Laravel with Vite. I have multiple JS files and including them whenever I want to use. But I cannot use the function I created in one file in another file.

Answer (score 1):

On you `main.js` file try using a different approarch like so:

```
window.testFunction = function() {
  alert('test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each file is going to be wrapped to actually prevent what you are attempting to do, unless explicitly defined on the window object *(notice how `window.Alpine = Alpine;` is set in your app.js)*. An alternative and more modern way is to use exports. Here is an example using your file structure.

**main.js:**

```
function testFunction() {
    alert('test');
}

export default testFunction;
```

**edit-note-page.js:**

```
import testFunction from './path/to/file/name';

...code here
```

The path to the file in the import does not need the extension .js at the end.

Note: After this change, you no longer need `import './main.js';` inside of app.js

Comment: It seems a little strange to me.

Imagine a case in Laravel:

I have a function.js file with 10 functions and 5 global variables. In order to access these functions, do I have to do import and export to be able to access them from another place?

Is it that if on a blade I only have one onepage.js file that loads only on one page but it has to access two functions that are in function.js, which are shared with some files, do I have to be doing import and export?

I see it a little repetitive, but if there is no other option...

Comment: Hey @Sylar you don't 'have to' really. If you wanted you could create functions directly on the window. However to answer your main point, yes, you export your dependencies and import them where you want to use them. This is true in almost all modern implementations of every modern language. All of these languages have ways where you don't need to do it. However imagine trying to find a problem with "globalFunctionZ" which is called 300 lines into a file and you aren't even sure where it came from.